# Error while installing supervisor in linux openSUSE 13.1

Tags: python, linux, supervisord, opensuse

I tried installing supervisor in my linux openSUSE 13.1 by

```
sudo zypper install supervisor
```

I am getting

> Supervisor not found in package names.Trying capabilities
>   No provider of supervisor found.

Even i tried installing by `**pip3 install supervisor**

It is raising an error like `supervisor requires with python 2.4 or later but doesnot work on`any version of python3

Am using python3.4. Is there any way to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

Please don't install python2.4 anywhere anymore, unless you absolutely have to. You probably don't. For reasons unknown openSUSE doesn't include supervisor in the main repositories, though usually python packages are covered pretty well.

Supervisor is a daemon that supervises processes, be they python programs or any other. It is something you should usually install system wide (IMO) and not in a virtualenv. As always, your case may be the exception to the rule.

Here are the [instructions](https://software.opensuse.org/download.html?project=devel%3Alanguages%3Apython&package=supervisor) for installing supervisor from the development repositories for openSUSE 13.1:

```
zypper addrepo http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/devel:languages:python/openSUSE_13.1/devel:languages:python.repo
zypper refresh
zypper install supervisor
```

The package will install required dependencies along with it, including the proper python2 version.

Python3 support is [coming](https://github.com/Supervisor/supervisor/issues/110) [to](https://github.com/Supervisor/supervisor#supported-platforms) supervisor at some point, but for the time being consider it python2 only, unless you feel very very adventurous. This on the other hand matters very little, as you usually do not need to even think about supervisor being a python program. You use it like any other system service daemon.

Comment: I get this error `File '/repositories/devel:languages:python/openSUSE_13.1/devel:languages:python.repo' not found on medium 'http://download.opensuse.org/'
`

Comment: @Jonathan It seems support for 13.1 has been dropped in that repository, or it's a transient error. You can verify yourself by going to http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/devel:/languages:/python/ that the folder `openSUSE_13.1` is gone, the oldest now being for 13.2.

Answer (score 0):

If the first mentioned repo doesn't try the following:

```
zypper addrepo http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/devel:languages:python/openSUSE_Tumbleweed/devel:languages:python.repo
zypper refresh
zypper install supervisor
```

Answer (score -1):

If it is saying you that it doesn't work in any version Python3, try to install python 2.4 also, so you will have both python3.4 and python2.4 together. This way, you will can install. If the problem is only the python version, of course.

Comment: I am deploying my django application in server and django 1.9 will support only with python2.7, 3.4 and 3.5.  Myvirtualenv has only python3.4 and not any 2.x versions. But still you want me to install 2.4 version inside my virtualenv and then try installing supervisor?

Comment: you can have more than one version of python: python 3.X and python 2.X, if you don't have in repositories try to compile the new version you require from source code.
If you say yor django app requires python 2.7, just add this, because supervisor requires newer than 2.4 but not 3.X...